# Restrict mutable object inside immutable object Java

Tags: java, immutability

I am learning about immutable Objects.  I am trying this code

```
  public final class ImmutableObject {

    private final String name;

    private final NormalObject obj =  new NormalObject();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public ImmutableObject(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        obj.setName(name);
    }


    public NormalObject getObj() {

        NormalObject tempObj = obj;
        return tempObj;
    }
}

public class NormalObject {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I want to restrict the calling class from changing the value of name variable of NormalObject

But the following code changes the value

```
 ImmutableObject obj = new ImmutableObject("Siddle");

 System.out.println(obj.getObj().getName()); //prints Siddle
 obj.getObj().setName("Kelly");

 System.out.println(obj.getObj().getName()); //prints Kelly
```

How to restrict it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an object to be immutable, **all** of its properties must be immutable. Its state must not be changeable.

To do that, you have to put an immutable facade on `NormalObject`, you can't directly return a `NormalObject`. The method that returns it will also need a different return type, you can't return `NormalObject` but actually return something that doesn't behave like a `NormalObject`.

E.g.:

```
public final class ImmutableObject {

    private final String name;

    private final NormalObject obj =  new NormalObject();

    private final ImmutableNormalObject objFacade = new ImmutableNormalObject(obj);

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public ImmutableObject(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        obj.setName(name);
    }

    public ImmutableNormalObject getObj() {

        return objFacade;
    }
}

public class NormalObject {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class ImmutableNormalObject {

    private NormalObject obj;

    public ImmutableNormalObject(Normalobject o) {
        this.obj = o;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return obj.getName();
    }
}
```

Alternately, if it's acceptable to copy the object and it has a copy constructor (or you can add one), you could do that, but copy-and-return is expensive.

Comment: Can I consider your code as an example of Facade Design patttern http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242429/what-is-facade-design-pattern ?

Comment: @mvg: Yes, it's an example of that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by returning a copy of your `normalObject` in getter:

```
public NormalObject getObj() {
    return new NormalObject(obj.getName());
    // or you can make a copy constructor:
    // return new NormalObject(obj);
}
```

Or you can make a wrapper for your `NormalObject` that ignores name setter, but it brakes logic.

Answer (score 0):

Please change Your NormalObject code to

```
public final class ImmutableObject {

    private final String name;
    // initialise it to null
    private final NormalObject obj = null;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public ImmutableObject(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        // use the Constructor for setting name only once during initialization of ImmutableObject via its constructor
        obj =  new NormalObject(name);

        //obj.setName(name);
    }


    public NormalObject getObj() {

        NormalObject tempObj = obj;
        return tempObj;
    }
}
```

NormalObject Class

```
public class NormalObject {

    private String name;
    public NormalObject(name){
     this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    //Remove any setter on NormalObject
    /*public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }*/

}
```

Comment: I like the NormalObject to remain as is.  I want only ImmutableObject's variable to be restricted.

Answer (score 0):

In an immutable object, if a User tries to change the state of the Object. either you won't allow or return a new Instance of the Immutable class.

So, since Date is a mutable class.
You can create an immutable wrapper around date, and you can expose only those methods, that are subject to be used in your Immutable-Date's perspective, but you return a new instance of your Immutable class, with the changed attribute of your new Date.

I don't think final would be required for Immutable variable, because it is already private and Immutable.

Example :

```
public class Main{

  private ImmutableDate immutableDate;

  public Main() {
    this.immutableDate = new ImmutableDate(new Date());
  }

  public Main(Date date){
    this.immutableDate = new ImmutableDate(date);
  }

  public ImmutableDate getDate() {
    return immutableDate;
  }

  public class ImmutableDate{
    // private constructor, so this can only be instantiated within the outer class
    // therefore, final keyword not required for Date, as no access given to the variable
    private Date date;
    private ImmutableDate(Date date) {
      this.date = date;
    }

    // Example methods from Date, that are required for our Immutable implementation

    public Main setTime(long time){
      Date date1 = new Date();
      date1.setTime(time);
      return new Main(date1);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return date.toString();
    }
  }
}
```