# How to prevent changes in a mutable object in immutable object

Tags: java, immutability

Can anybody tell how we can prevent a user to modify the values of an mutable object define in an immutable class ?

Example :
We have a immutable `Student` class, which contains final reference of `Address` class, which is mutable. I want to prevent the user to make any change in `Address` class?

Comment: You provide constructor initialization for Address class, keeping all members of it private and without any setters

Comment: Wouldn't that make the `Address` class effectively immutable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrict mutable object inside immutable object Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189235/restrict-mutable-object-inside-immutable-object-java)

Comment: @DonRoby : Thanks.!! Got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Arrange for `Address` to be an `interface`. Make your mutable `MutableAddress` as normal and make an `ImmutableAddress` that wraps it preventing write access to the fields.

```
interface Address {

    public String getNumber();

    public void setNumber(String number) throws IllegalAccessException;

    public String getStreet();

    public void setStreet(String street) throws IllegalAccessException;

    public String getZip();

    public void setZip(String zip) throws IllegalAccessException;

}

class MutableAddress implements Address {

    String number;
    String street;
    String zip;

    @Override
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    @Override
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    @Override
    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    @Override
    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    @Override
    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

}

class ImmutableAddress implements Address {

    private final Address address;

    public ImmutableAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNumber() {
        return address.getNumber();
    }

    @Override
    public void setNumber(String number) throws IllegalAccessException {
        throw new IllegalAccessException("Cannot write to this field.");
    }

    @Override
    public String getStreet() {
        return address.getStreet();
    }

    @Override
    public void setStreet(String street) throws IllegalAccessException {
        throw new IllegalAccessException("Cannot write to this field.");
    }

    @Override
    public String getZip() {
        return address.getZip();
    }

    @Override
    public void setZip(String zip) throws IllegalAccessException {
        throw new IllegalAccessException("Cannot write to this field.");
    }

}
```

Alternatively, wrap it in a [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html). This is much more complicated but can help when you do not have access to the sources.