# Can this (below) be considered a facade (structural design pattern)?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

```
function BankOperationChecker() {
    //This is the facade
    this.applyFor = function(facadeMethods) {
        for (var method in facadeMethods) {
            facadeMethods[method]();
        }
    }
}

function BankClient(name, amount) {
    this.name = name;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.bankOperations = new BankOperationChecker();
}

var client = new BankClient("Davi Vieira", 2000);
var checkMethods = {
    cleanBackground: function() {
        console.log('The background of this client is clean.');
    },
    canGetCredit: function() {
        if (client.amount > 1000) {
            console.log('Can get credit!');
        } else {
            console.log('Cannot get credit!');
        }
    }
}

client.bankOperations.applyFor(checkMethods);
```

What do you think? Facade for entrance is just one... but is that right? Is there any specific rules about creating a facade?

Comment: What do you think? Have you thought anything?

Comment: Very wierd design. Whats the benefit of having BankOperationChecker aggregated inside Client here? You aren't even making use of the client instance dynamically. The BankOperationChecker also doesn't seem to actually check anything... it just executes methods in a loop.

Comment: Facade pattern is a pretty global design pattern since most every abstraction of code could be called a "facade". But in your case as you expose your BankOperationChecker function class I hope it would break part of the pattern. Take a look at Addy's book https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#facadepatternjavascript

Comment: Nope, that's nothing to do with a [facade](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5242429/1048572).

Comment: Hey guys! thanks a lot for the comments. I studied a little and read what you write. So i tried again: https://gist.github.com/davivieira/5a71b73662009653ca40cebdeeeb85c8

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't.

Facade, in English, means 'the face of a building, especially the principal front that looks onto a street or open space'. Because of this, many people confuse Facade pattern as something that acts as an entrance to something else- that, however, is not so.

As per [this](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/facade), the intents behind Facade patterns are:

> - Provide a unified interface to a set of interfaces in a subsystem. Facade defines a higher-level interface that makes the subsystem easier to use.
> - Wrap a complicated subsystem with a simpler interface.

Your example neither has bunch of subsystems nor does it have one interface to wrap all of them.