# Java's "Scanner" Method vs. Facade GoF Design Pattern

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, facade

I'm studying design patterns to improve my programming skills. Right now, I'm exploring the facade design pattern.

I may be confusing myself, but, as an example: isn't the `Scanner` is a facade?
Note that I'm not asking what is a Facade, but trying to identify if Scanner is.

Well, I declare it so I can use certain features without contacting complex and deeper functions, right?

I declare

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

so I can:

```
String x = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the facade design pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242429/what-is-the-facade-design-pattern).

Comment: Not really.  `Scanner` provides functionality that `InputStream` doesn't, so it's not really a Facade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example of class which simplifies an API and makes it clear and closer to what is used for. When we want to read data from user in console app `InputStream` would be hard to use. Let's take a look on some definition of [Facade](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/facade) pattern and match with `Scanner` class:

### Intent

- Provide a unified interface to a set of interfaces in a subsystem.
  Facade defines a higher-level interface that makes the subsystem
  easier to use.
- Wrap a complicated subsystem with a simpler interface.

`Scanner` class matches both above points.

### Check list

1. Identify a simpler, unified interface for the subsystem or
   component.
2. Design a 'wrapper' class that encapsulates the subsystem.
3. The facade/wrapper captures the complexity and collaborations of the
   component, and delegates to the appropriate methods.
4. The client uses (is coupled to) the Facade only.
5. Consider whether additional Facades would add value.

`Scanner` class matches all above points. So, we can consider `Scanner` as a facade for `InputStream`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I think I'm going on the right path

Comment: `Scanner` does not unify any set of interfaces, nor does it simplify the `Readable` interface it wraps. The `Scanner` API is far more complex than `Readable`.

Comment: @jaco0646, `Facade` can simplify `API` for one `interface` as well. Of course, it is much clear to see it when we have more than one but one is enough. Maybe it has much complex `API` than `Readable` but it makes it easier to use when we read data from console. `parseInt`, `nextLine`, `hasNextLine` as much simpler to understand and use than `read` next bytes. Also, we can create other `Facade` over `Scanner` which simplifies console usage for our requirements. For example, in case we need to read only a few numbers from console we can limit `Scanner` `API` to required methods only.

Answer (score 1):

Facade consolidates a one-to-many relationship into a one-to-one relationship for its clients. They become simpler because they depend on one (high-level) Facade rather than many (low-level) individual components. The Facade itself takes over the many low-level dependencies (and delegates to them).

The relationship of `Scanner` to its `Readable source` is plain old object composition. There is no consolidation of dependencies. While it's true that `Scanner` provides new functionality and is a higher-level abstraction than `Readable`, that is true of many or most composition relationships.

A Facade both reduces dependencies (coupling) and increases abstraction for its clients. Notice that diagrams of the Facade Pattern always show *multiple* outgoing arrows from the Facade object.