# Can a JsonGenerator write to an OutputStream and Writer in the same call?

Tags: java, java-io

Is there an elegant solution or pattern so that one invoke of writeStartObject() can be applied to both the Writer and the OutputStream?

```
        try (
        JsonGenerator output = jfactory.createGenerator(outputWriter); // writer
        JsonGenerator cachingOutput = jfactory.createGenerator(cachingService.getCachingOutputStream(id));//outputstream
    ) {
        output.writeStartObject();
        cachingOutput.writeStartObject();
        ...
```

Comment: I guess you can use the [facade design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242429/what-is-the-facade-design-pattern). But I think that is more overhead and does not bring much more readability.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider whether these two really should be bound together as there are cohesion and coupling guidelines to consider.  For example, if you need to use the `writer` or the `outputStream` for other uses and to an extensive degree then you should keep them separate unless this extensive use is reflected across both of them equally.  It may be better to hide both of these behind two independent [Data Access Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) where their use can be compartmentalized, exposing their operations in a descriptive manner based on the purpose for accessing them - a little more suited to your business.

Whether it's limited use or extensive use, for equal use across the pair I might apply a [façade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) as such:

```
class SimultaneousFeed {
    private JFactory jFactory;
    private JsonGenerator out;
    private JsonGenerator writer;
    SimultaneousFeed(JFactory jFactory, OutputStream outputStream, Writer outputWriter) {
        this.jFactory = jFactory;
        this.out = jfactory.createGenerator(outputStream);
        this.writer = jfactory.createGenerator(outputWriter);
    }
    void writeStartObject() {
        out.writeStartObject();
        writer.writeStartObject();
    }
    ...
    // other operations common to the pair of these outputs
}

...

SimultaneousFeed feed = new SimultaneousFeed(jFactory, cachingService.getCachingOutputStream(id),
        outputWriter);
feed.writeStartObject();
```

Note that I'm passing the `OutputStream` to the new `SimultaneousFeed` instance rather than passing the `id`.  Passing the `id` raises the [data coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) in the new instance - the `id` is a piece of data the `SimultaneousFeed` should know nothing about.  This allows the `SimultaneousFeed` to concern itself with only output data, improving reusability and maintainability.

An alternative pattern to consider would be the [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern, provided you're able to subclass the class of the `jfactory` instance and the `JsonGenerator` class.  This would allow you to create a custom `JsonGenerator` that simultaneously writes to the two outputs in an overridden implementation of the `writeStartObject()` method.  In that case, you could provide a method in the `jfactory` class:

```
public JsonGenerator createSimultaneousGenerator(OutputStream outputStream, Writer outputWriter) {
    return new SimulJsonGenerator(outputStream, outputWriter);
}
```